# What would cause the cam carriers to shatter on my BMW 3 Series (2011)

Tags: bmw, timing, camshaft

The timing chain has stretched and the cam carriers have shattered after only 72,000 miles. What could cause this? I have found out that the car was mapped/chipped by the previous owner. Have no idea about cars. PLEASE HELP. The car needs a new engine. If the re mapping caused this, then I'm hoping the car dealer (who didn't notify me it had been re mapped when I bought it 7 months ago) will be liable for the costs.

Comment: I am pretty sure BMW had a design issue with those engines which cause excessive chain stretch. I'm pretty sure it was up to the consumer to perform maintenance on the chain, even though it was originally designed as a "lifetime" part for the engine. BMW put something out in a tech bulletin, but didn't do anything themselves to fix the issue (and won't). I'm leaving this as a comment until I can dig up stuff to confirm my suspicions (or until someone else answers this question).

Comment: Which model is this? Also, petrol or diesel?

Comment: What I do not see immediately is the relationship between tuning the chip (essentially varying fuel injection quantity and timing) and cam problems. I would mostly associate chip tuning with the head overheating, a turbo melting and lower-end problems with the crankshaft bearings. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?  If so, please post the solution to the issue or even the cause of it.  Very interesting.  I hope it didn't beat your wallet to death closing it out!  Cheers